# Pandas: Best way to count matches between two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, collections

I have a dataframe like:

```
   actual  prediction
0       1           0
1       0           0
2       0           0  
3       1           0 
4       1           1
5       0           0
```

Is there a pythonic way to get a result similar to:

```
number of (0, 0) = 3
number of (0, 1) = 0
number of (1, 0) = 2
number of (1, 1) = 1
```

I don't need it exactly like that, and I have several versions of code that can accomplish this, but it seems way too verbose. What is the pythonic way to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas solution (not that nice compared to @Divakar's compact Numpy solution):

```
from itertools import product

In [291]: cats = ['{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format(tup) for tup in product([0,1], [0,1])]

In [292]: pd.Categorical((df.actual.astype(str)+df.prediction.astype(str)),
                         categories=cats) \
            .value_counts()
Out[292]:
00    3
01    0
10    2
11    1
dtype: int64
```

if you don't need to list missing combinations like `(0, 1)`:

```
In [298]: df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index()
Out[298]:
   actual  prediction  0
0       0           0  3
1       1           0  2
2       1           1  1
```

Comment: Wow and I was expecting some `groupby` based compact solution from you gurus! Like `groupby` and then `value_counts`?

Comment: @Divakar, I had to use categorical dtype in order to have # of missing combinations like `(0, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

If we are dealing with `0s` and `1s`, here's one way with `dot-product` -

```
np.bincount(df.dot([2,1]))
```

Comment: @nevabyte That's why the mention of `If` part at the start.

Comment: Posted my comment before you edited your question to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

adding a custom category should work :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"actual":[0,0,0,1,2,3],"prediction":[0,0,1,2,15,14]})
df['customCategory'] = (df.actual.apply(lambda x: str(x)+',')+df.prediction.astype(str))
df.groupby('customCategory').customCategory.count()
```